# BVP4C scipỳ solver in two different space regions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of two second order differential equations in two different space regions:

y1'' = f(x, y1) for   -x1<=x<=0

y2'' = g(x, y2) for     0<=x<=x2

with known boundary conditions y1(-x1) and y2(x2), and I also know that y1'(x=0) = y2'(x=0) and y1(x=0)=y2(x=0), i.e. the y functions and their derivatives must be continuous in x=0. (In fact, there should be only one function y, but I have split it in two for clarity).

In Matlab there is a very simple way to solve this problem; the matlab solver bv4c includes this possibility.

I'm not able to figure out how (if it is possible) to solve this problem using the scipy bv4pv solver. Can anybody help me with this question?
Thank you.

Comment: You mean `solve_bvp`, and no, there is no such functionality, no multiple shooting solver with more than 2 condition points. You can of course always implement a single shooting method via the ODE solver and a non-linear solver.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only want to use solve_bvp in some problems in physics (I'm professor of a university), and I would like my student simulate the problems and discuss the results, not he mathematical method. Nevertheless, thank you again for your quick and clear answer.

Comment: In this special situation where the inner conditions are just the usual continuity conditions, you might get along with having a branching in the ODE and the point x=0 in the initial mesh, as the mesh only gets refined by the solver and the collocation conditions should impose nothing more than continuity at the nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try. I think this is the simplest case. The following step, if I get  successful with this case, would be  imposing a finite discontinuity in the derivatives, i.e.y1'(0) = y'2(0)+C; being C a known value. I'm working on the shooting method to try to implement it in these cases.